# PHP laravel Moltin-cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm using Laravel 5.1.x, when I try to install Moltin laravel-cart is says:

```
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 5.1.x-dev
- moltin/laravel-cart dev-master requires laravel/framework 4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev].
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming about as a result of the moltin/laravel-cart library requiring any version of Laravel 4. It looks like it isn't happy with having Laravel 5 as a version. You'll have a couple of options from this point.

1. Copy the moltin/laravel-cart source into your project
2. Fork the moltin/laravel-cart project and update the composer.json to accept Laravel 5 as a dependency.

Comment: Where to copy ? Can you provide steps ? I'm new to this stuffs. Thanks!